# How to update the table data using stored procedure in MS access datasheet view

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I'm working with MS access front end and sql server backend.I have created a Pass-through query and i have the "Exec storedProcedurename" in the passthough query.when i create a datasheet view for this pass-through query the fields are non editable.Is it possible to make the datasheet view fields editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you cannot do this.  Here's a previous answer on this topic:

[How to make a passthrough / passthru query editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898032/how-to-make-a-passthrough-passthru-query-editable)

Comment: Thank you for the response.Currently we are using View in the update-able datasheet and we are planning to change the view as it affects the performance.which is the best way to replace views in update-able datasheet?

Comment: Are linked tables an option you have considered?

Comment: What are the tables lacking that made you consider using an SP? If you wanted to apply logic on top of your data you can use views (you'll need to set a PKey to make editable - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20474851/2572928).